# Is it possible to access rows in a group when we use group by

Tags: sql

I have a table like follows in which `country` could be duplicated.

```
CustomerID  CustomerName                        ContactName     Address City PostalCode Country
1           Alfreds Futterkiste                 Maria Anders    Obere Str. 57   Berlin  12209   Germany
2           Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados  Ana Trujillo    Avda. de la Constitución 2222   México D.F. 05021   Mexico
3           Antonio Moreno Taquería             Antonio Moreno  Mataderos 2312  México D.F. 05023   Mexico
...
```

I created a query which would tell me the count per country (eg 4 records, for Germany, 2 for Mexico etc.).

```
select Country, count(Country) AS Count 
from (
  SELECT * 
  FROM Customers 
  order by Country
) 
group by Country
```

I get

```
Country City    count
Argentina       3
Austria         2
```

I suppose The columns listed in the GROUP BY clause are used to form groups. The grouping is based on rows with the same value in the specified column or columns being placed in the same group. So in above example, `Argentina` group contains 3 rows. Is is possible that I can get access to individual rows which are in a group so that I can also output the cities in the result?

Something like

```
Country     City                  count
Argentina   city1, city2, city3   3
Austria     city1, city2          2
```

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Some offer GROUP_CONCAT aggregation function that does exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes. It's possible. But what is your RDBMS?

Comment: practising on `W3Schools` website. Don't know which `DB` they use

Comment: DBMS is your answer

Comment: why is the question marked down?

Comment: The derived table and the order by are totally useless. Your query is equivalent to `select Country, count(Country) AS Count from customers order by country`

Comment: You're probably getting downvotes because you don't specify which dbms you're using. Without that information, the problem can't be solved.

Comment: I guess the dbms is sql server most of the times i have seen on w3 schools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join grouped table to original table:

```
select cu.*, co.cnt from Customers cu
join  (
    select Country, count(Country) cnt AS Count
    from Customers
    group by Country
) co on cu.Country = co.Country
```

This is standard SQL and should work on arbitrary RDBMS (at least on most of them).

Depending on RDBMS, you could use some specific methods, such us string aggregation or window functions (SSMS).

Comment: sorry, I don't understand how this will give me access to individual cities in a group

Comment: @ManuChadha Use `cu.City` to access it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the code below.

ALTER PROC dbo.GEN_SP_G_CONCATDATAs
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @CountryName AS INT, @RowCtry AS INT = 1, @Cities AS VARCHAR(max) = '', @RowCity AS INT = 1
DECLARE @tmpTableCountry TABLE(ID INT,Country VARCHAR(max))
INSERT INTO @tmpTableCountry
    ( ID, Country )
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ISNULL(Country,0) ASC) , -- ID - int
    ISNULL(Country,0)  -- Country - varchar(max)
FROM dbo.tmpCustomerTable
GROUP BY Country
WHILE @RowCtry <= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @tmpTableCountry)
BEGIN
    SELECT @CountryName =  ISNULL(Country,'') FROM @tmpTableCountry WHERE ID = @RowCtry

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#tmpTableCity') is not null
drop table #tmpTableCity
CREATE TABLE #tmpTableCity(ID INT,City VARCHAR(max))

INSERT INTO #tmpTableCity
        ( ID, City )
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CustomerID ASC) , -- ID - int
        City  -- Country - varchar(max)
FROM dbo.tmpCustomerTable
WHERE Country = @CountryName 

SET @Cities = ''
SET @RowCity = 1    

DECLARE @cnt AS INT = 0

SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM #tmpTableCity

WHILE @RowCity <= @cnt
    BEGIN
        SET @Cities = @Cities + (SELECT ISNULL(City,'') FROM #tmpTableCity WHERE ID = @RowCity) + ','
        SET @RowCity = @RowCity + 1
    END

DECLARE @tmpTableResult TABLE(Country VARCHAR(max),City VARCHAR(max),Cnt INT)

INSERT INTO @tmpTableResult
        ( Country, City, Cnt )
VALUES  ( @CountryName, -- Country - varchar(max)
          @Cities, -- City - varchar(max)
          @cnt  -- Cnt - int
          )

SET @RowCtry = @RowCtry + 1
```

END

SELECT * FROM @tmpTableResult
END
GO

Answer (score -1):

```
select country, city, count(*) as count
from customers
group by country, city
order by country, city
```

or

```
SELECT country, 
LISTAGG(city, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY city) as cities,
count (*) as count 
FROM customers
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY country
```

Comment: this will print multiple times country,city if city is different and country is same

Comment: yes , if you using oracle you can use LISTAGG, to produce a comma separated list of cities for each country: SELECT country,
       LISTAGG(city, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY city) as cities
  FROM customers
  GROUP BY country
  ORDER BY country;

Comment: thats what I am saying theres no surity the dbms is oracle edit again to generate generalised sql for all dbms

Comment: I updated my answer and I believe it produces the desired result now. if so please mark the answer as correct. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks Ted. I tried your answer but for total 91 records, your query showed only 69